# jQuery plugin with or without a selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I have created a plugin that turns the selector element into a Modal Popup.

For example:

```
$(".ModalPopup").ModalPopup();
```

However there are instances where the `ModalPopup` element won't exist within the DOM.

In this instance I would like to dynamically create the `ModalPopup` element **within** the plugin and therefore just be able to call:

```
$.ModalPopup();
```

Is it possible to have a jQuery plugin that works with and without a selector?

If so, how can I do this? I currently have (simplified):

```
;(function ($,window,document,undefined) {

    function ModalPopup(element, options){
        this.element = element;

        this.options = $.extend({}, defaults, options);

        this._defaults = defaults;
        this._name = pluginName;

        this.init();

    }

    $.fn[pluginName] = function (options) { 
       new ModalPopup(this, options);  
    };

})(jQuery, window, document);
```

Comment: Yes it works with or without one. That depends on how you create it.

Comment: You would have to extend `$` instead of `$.fn`. This is not the same plugin pattern, to my knowledge most plugins implement either one of the other, not both.

Comment: I don't think you can develop a plugin because plugin work of dom element instances

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Thanks for your response. What would you suggest in this instance then? Create a seperate function which creates the element and calls the plugin?

Comment: @Curt, yes, you could write a `$.foo()` method that creates the element, appends it to the DOM, then invokes `$.fn.foo()` on that element.